# smart way to use apply or aternative

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have this dataframe:

```
dates,real.rev,ax.rev,be.rev,real.Qout,ax.Qout,be.Qout
2018-01-01 00:00:00,0.01,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
2018-01-01 01:00:00,0.01,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
2018-01-01 02:00:00,0.03,0.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,0.0
2018-01-01 03:00:00,0.0,0.0,0.0,5.0,0.0,0.0
2018-01-01 04:00:00,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0
2018-01-01 05:00:00,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
2018-01-01 06:00:00,0.01,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,10.0
2018-01-01 07:00:00,0.04,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
2018-01-01 08:00:00,0.01,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
2018-01-01 09:00:00,0.04,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
2018-01-01 10:00:00,0.01,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
2018-01-01 11:00:00,0.01,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
2018-01-01 12:00:00,0.01,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
2018-01-01 13:00:00,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
2018-01-01 14:00:00,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
2018-01-01 15:00:00,0.01,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
2018-01-01 16:00:00,0.01,0.0,286.572,0.0,0.0,0.7
2018-01-01 17:00:00,6139.98,0.0,0.0,13.7,0.0,0.0
```

I would like to substitute the values in columns "real.Qout", "ax.Qout" and "be.Qout" with 0 or 1 according to the value in the column. For example, all value greater than 2 with 1 and value less than 1 with 0.

An option, if I have understood correctly, could be to apply a sort of "apply method". A sort of:

```
dfObj['be.Qout'] = dfObj['be.Qout'].apply(np.square)
```

I would like to, of course, not use np.square. I would like also apply this to real.Qout,ax.Qout,be.Qout.

Thanks for any kind of help,
D.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [lambda with if-else](https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-use-if-else-elif-in-lambda-functions/) with [applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) as follows-

```
dfObj[['real.Qout', 'ax.Qout', 'be.Qout']] = dfObj[['real.Qout', 'ax.Qout', 'be.Qout']].applymap(lambda x : 1 if x > 2 else 0)
```

Comment: ya, now I can test.

Answer (score 1):

I think better here is avoid `apply/applymap`, because loops under th hood, so slow. Better is use some vectorized solutions with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
cols = ["real.Qout", "ax.Qout", "be.Qout"]
df[cols] = np.where(df[cols] > 2, 1, 0)
```

Or if want set `0` with `1` only convert mask to integers:

```
df[cols] = (df[cols] > 2).astype(int)
```

If want set by multiple conditions use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
cols = ["real.Qout", "ax.Qout", "be.Qout"]
df[cols] = np.select([df[cols] > 2, df[cols] < 0.5], [1,2], default=0)
```

Some tests in 18k rows:

```
#18k rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

cols = ["real.Qout", "ax.Qout", "be.Qout"]


In [84]: %timeit df[cols] = (df[cols] > 2).astype(int)
1.77 ms ± 13.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [85]: %timeit df[cols] = np.where(df[cols] > 2, 1, 0)
17.1 ms ± 65.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [86]: %timeit df[['real.Qout', 'ax.Qout', 'be.Qout']] = df[['real.Qout', 'ax.Qout', 'be.Qout']].applymap(lambda x : 1 if x > 2 else 0)
24.3 ms ± 279 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```